# My Serial plotter isn't working (arduino)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm trying to upload this code and it works properly but I can't see anything on my serial plotter

```
const int AnalogIn_Pin0=  A0;
const int AnalogIn_Pin1=A1;
const int Pwmout_PIN=11;
float AnalogIn_Val0=0;
float AnalogIn_Val1=0;
int Pwmout_Val=0;
float Error=0;
float ErrorInteg=0;
float Control=0;
float ControlFilt=0;
float kp=0.2;
float Pole =-10;
float Ki =0.01;
int deltaT=0.01;
int deltaT_ms=(int)deltaT*1000;


void setup() {
  pinMode (Pwmout_PIN,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  AnalogIn_Val0=(float)constrain (analogRead(AnalogIn_Pin0),0,600);
  AnalogIn_Val1=0.97*AnalogIn_Val1+0.03*(float)analogRead(AnalogIn_Pin1);
  Error= (AnalogIn_Val0-AnalogIn_Val1);
  ErrorInteg=ErrorInteg+Error*deltaT;
  ControlFilt=kp*Error+Ki *ErrorInteg;
  Pwmout_Val= constrain (map ((int)ControlFilt,0,1023,0,255),0,220);
 analogWrite (Pwmout_PIN,Pwmout_Val);
 Serial.print(AnalogIn_Val0);
 Serial.print("");
 Serial.print(AnalogIn_Val1);
 Serial.print("");
 Serial.print( Pwmout_Val);
 delay (deltaT_ms); 


}
```

Comment: `works properly` ... then why did you post your question?

Comment: you do not say what you actually see ..... maybe your plotter is defective

Comment: it's not plotting, the hardware works properly

Comment: It looks like that will just output a long string of numbers. No separators between fields, no separators between records (like: `5678298549328756238746524983759823462938746238974692387463298574369587234658723468734629375605237643724123046503453948765...`. How is anything supposed to make sense of the data?

Answer (score 1):

You must have each set of data point (or points) on a separate line and if you are plotting more that one value you need a space or a tab between each value.

So to have 3 lines on your plot, I think you want this:

```
 Serial.print(AnalogIn_Val0);
 Serial.print(' ');
 Serial.print(AnalogIn_Val1);
 Serial.print(' ');
 Serial.println(Pwmout_Val);
```

The output in the serial monitor should be something like this:

```
123 456 789
234 567 901
...
```